# Join database table based on Json colum having multiple key

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to create an ecommerce application using laravel, So when someone orders something, I store data in orders table, in which a column "products" exists.
I store json object in this column.
this is products json:

```
[{"pid":65,"min_price":"349.0000"},{"pid":71,"min_price":"349.0000"}]
```

Now, I want to show these order details to the user profile. So, i need to fetch rows from an another table (products), with the primary key same as "pid" in given json object.

please, suggest me how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without retrieving it first and looping over it or something.

What you might want to consider is the following:

Remove the column products from the orders table and create a `order_product` table. This is called a pivot table.
You can create this table by running the command `php artisan create:migration CreateOrderProductTable`

Now in this table you define 2 foreign keys. order_id and product_id.

If you have done this, you have to create the relations in the Product model and the Order model.

You can now use this relation to query all products that an order has like this: `Order::find(1)->products()->get()`